# MODX Manager appears as a blank page after login

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I've got a site thats been up for over a year. Today, however, I tried to login to the dashboard today and was presented with a blank screen.

The login form appeared fine, but just redirected to a blank page.

I've cleaned the cache manually and toggled the News and Security feeds and the css and js compress options via the database to no effect.

Would anyone know what I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, but I reinstalled and it fixed it.